# How can I modify my code so that images from a list appear in rows and tiles?

Tags: python, pygame

What I am doing is creating a memory Tile game that requires a list of 8 images to appear at once twice each. This is the portion of my code that is have issues.

```
self.images_1_2_8 = ['image1.bmp','image2.bmp','image3.bmp','image4.bmp','image5.bmp','image6.bmp','image8.bmp','image7.bmp','image1.bmp','image2.bmp','image3.bmp','image4.bmp','image5.bmp','image6.bmp','image7.bmp','image8.bmp']

  self.collect_images = []
  for select_images in self.images_1_2_8:       
     image = pygame.image.load(select_images)

     #width = image.get_width()
     #height = image.get_height()
     random.shuffle(self.self.images_1_2_8)

  for row_index in range(0, self.board_size):
     row = []
     for col_index in range(0,self.board_size):
        width = image.get_width()
        height = image.get_height()            
        x = width * col_index
        y = height * row_index
        tile = Tile(x,y, self.select_images_1_2_8[image_index], self.surface)         row.append(tile)
     self.board.append(row)
```

The error message that I keep getting is:
builtins.TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not subscriptable

I found out that this means that the **getitem**() property isn't reading my images as a list? I think that's what it means. The images appear (only one image from the list, which fills all 16 indexes) if I remove the list [row_index*self.board_size+col_index].

I know it's an easy fix but I'm brand new to python and I've been at this for weeks now... Thank you in advance if anyone is able to help!

Comment: What is `image[]` ?  The error makes it sound like it's a single image, not a list.

Comment: What line is throwing an exception?

Comment: @Kingsley I've updated with a better view of my code. image is what I used to identify the images that I loaded.

Comment: @VladBezden The portion throwing the error is tile = Tile(x,y,image[image_index],self.surface)
        row.append(tile)

Comment: @Kingsley thank you for your suggestion. When I previously (and just again) tried this method I recieved the error "builtins.TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable". I will try to post the whole code... it'll only take me a moment.

Comment: @VladBezden thank you for your help! Your method also gave me the not callable error. I shall try to post the whole code because I think I am leading everyone blind.

Comment: OMG it works you guys it works!!!!!!!! THANK YOU THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, it should be selecting from `collect_images` rather than `image` which is just the last (single) image loaded (not a list).  The code's almost there, just needs a tweak.

```
self.images_1_2_8 = ['image1.bmp','image2.bmp','image3.bmp','image4.bmp','image5.bmp','image6.bmp','image8.bmp','image7.bmp','image1.bmp','image2.bmp','image3.bmp','image4.bmp','image5.bmp','image6.bmp','image7.bmp','image8.bmp']

  self.collect_images = []
  for select_images in self.images_1_2_8:       
     image = pygame.image.load(select_images)
     self.collect_images.append(image)           # <-- make the list in collect_images
     #width = image.get_width()
     #height = image.get_height()
     random.shuffle(self.collect_images)         # <-- shuffle loaded images


  for row_index in range(0, self.board_size):
     row = []
     for col_index in range(0,self.board_size):
        width = image.get_width()
        height = image.get_height()            
        x = width * col_index
        y = height * row_index
        tile = Tile(x,y, collect_images[image_index], self.surface)  # <-- use the image-list
        row.append(tile)
     self.board.append(row)
```

There's no code for the updating of `image_index`.  Please ensure this is incrementing from 0 to within the maximum number of images in the list.